# Method to return a string function in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am a little programmer in C # , VB.NET do however have to code a lot of time . Now I was in doubt if the code was doing well . I need your help to create a function that makes the return of a string , already tested the following code , but the compiler gives an error :

```
public class Main
{
    private System.Text.UTF8Encoding enc;
    private ICryptoTransform encryptor;
    private ICryptoTransform decryptor;

    public string utf16_encrypt(string input)
    {
        string sPlainText = input;
        string output;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPlainText))
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, this.encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cryptoStream.Write(enc.GetBytes(sPlainText), 0, sPlainText.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            output = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
            memoryStream.Close();
            cryptoStream.Close();
            return output;
        }
    }
}
```

The error given by the compiler is :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/cJeNran.png]

Comment: Use a `using` statement where you make a `new MemmoryStream` and a `new CryptoStream`. Not related to your question, but strongly encouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this : `return output;` out of the `}` brace like this :

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPlainText))
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, this.encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cryptoStream.Write(enc.GetBytes(sPlainText), 0, sPlainText.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                output = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
                memoryStream.Close();
                cryptoStream.Close();

            }
  return output;
```

Comment: New error given by compiler: Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'output' C:\Users\luisferreira\Organizados\Workspace\Projects\totalLibrary\totalLibrary\totalLibrary\main.cs 31 20 totalLibrary

Comment: @user3837675 assign that variable with default value of `null` or `string.Empty`.

Comment: Put `string output = "";` in your declaration.

Comment: Thank you, the compiler no longer returns any error .

Comment: Not a problem. You can do it as per your convinience. :)

Answer (score 2):

User, your method will not return anything if sPlainText is null. You have to keep this in mind and make sure all execution paths return code. You could change the code to be like this:

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPlainText))
                {
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, this.encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                    cryptoStream.Write(enc.GetBytes(sPlainText), 0, sPlainText.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    output = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
                    memoryStream.Close();
                    cryptoStream.Close();
                    return output;
                }

    return "Invalid Input"; //Or whatever message you want to pass back to the user/code.
```

Answer (score 1):

You should think what your function should do if it doesn't enter the if statement.

You need a default return statement. Right now if the condition is not true you return nothing. Instead write at the end something like :

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPlainText))
            {
                ...
                return output;
            }
  return String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

The really short version of your code is

```
    public string utf16_encrypt(string input)
    {
        string output;
        if (somecondition)
        {
           return output;
        }
    }
```

The compiler knows what to do if some condition is true, but if it's false, it has no idea. It's looking for something like

```
    public string utf16_encrypt(string input)
    {
        string output;
        if (somecondition)
        {
           return output;
        }
        else {
           return "banana"; //when in doubt, return bananas
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you that every logical path through the code must return a value.  Since the method declares a return type:

```
public string utf16_encrypt(string input)
```

it *must* return something of that type (`string`).  So the question becomes...

> What happens if `sPlainText` *is* null or empty?

If it isn't null or empty, the code returns something:

```
return output;
```

But if it isn't null or empty, then that `if` block is never executed and there is no `return` statement.  So you need to add one:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPlainText))
{
    // your current code
}
return output;
```

You don't have to return `output` specifically, I just guessed on what you might want to return.  You may return a default value instead, something like:

```
return string.Empty;
```

It's up to you.  The point is that logically the method must *always* return something (assuming it doesn't terminate in an exception condition instead).

Answer (score 0):

*Not all code parths return a value* is meaningful, isn't it?

You have to ensure that a value is returned from the method in any case. You return only from inside the `if`, so nothing is returned if  `sPlainText==null`. In that case you could return null:

```
public string utf16_encrypt(string input)
{
    string sPlainText = input;
    string output;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sPlainText))
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, this.encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(enc.GetBytes(sPlainText), 0, sPlainText.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        output = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        return output;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```

by the way, you also get a compiler *warning* in VB.NET if you comment out `Return Nothing`

```
Public Function utf16_encrypt(input As String) As String
    Dim sPlainText As String = input
    Dim output As String
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sPlainText) Then
        ' ... '
        Return output
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

better to do like this, looks a lot simpler and easier

```
 public string utf16_encrypt(string input)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return null;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, this.encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(enc.GetBytes(input), 0, input.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```